# How do I disable stretch effect on React Native Scrollview/Flatlist?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-scrollview

This is the effect I am describing. I am emulating using a Pixel 3 with API 32 on android studio. This page is a scrollview with no styling, and a bunch of views with color stylings and height and width set.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an effect added by Google in Android 12, this is called "overScroll".

You can turn it off in react-native by using `<ScrollView overScrollMode="never">`.

See React Native ScrollView doc [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#overscrollmode-android).